# Chaining subscription to multiple observables with parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to subscribe two observables one after the other. The order is important and must be kept. The first observable returns a result `itemId` which must be passed to the second subscription. Currently, I use nested subscriptions, which is not very nice. What is the cleanest way to implement this?

```
// 1
this.widget$
  .subscribe((widget) => {
    const itemId: number = widget.data[0].itemId;

    // 2
    this.store
      .select(DeviceHistoryStore.getItemHistoryEntries(this.deviceId, itemId))
      .subscribe((deviceHistory) => {
        const name = widget.name; 
        // Run code
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a [SwitchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap).

```
this.widget$.pipe(
    switchMap(widget => 
        this.store
            .select(DeviceHistoryStore.getItemHistoryEntries(
                this.deviceId, 
                widget.data[0].itemId
            ))
    )
).subscribe(deviceHistory => { /* ... */ )
```

Edit:

If you want to access `widget` in the subscribe callback:

```
this.widget$.pipe(
    switchMap(widget => 
        combineLatest([
            of(widget),
            this.store
                .select(DeviceHistoryStore.getItemHistoryEntries(
                    this.deviceId, 
                    widget.data[0].itemId
                ))
        ])        
    )
).subscribe(([widget, deviceHistory]) => { /* ... */ )
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question to your example. How can I access the `widget` inside the subscribe function?

Comment: i added another code snippet to my answer